# Android : INSERT with a FOREIGN KEY that corresponds not to a PRIMARY KEY

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

First, please forgive me for my approximative English.

I have 2 tables, one (tb_facture) with a foreign key referencing the second (tb_garage)

My problem is that I can't INSERT in the tb_facture without giving a foreign key that references tb_garage.

If I give a valid foreign key, there is no problem. But if I try to give -1 (or something else), it doesn't insert.

I must be able to do this because, in my app, it is not an obligation to link a garage to the invoice.

Here is the insertion code :

```
private void saveState(){
    String libelleFac = etLibelleFac.getText().toString();
    String dateFac = tvDateAfficheeFac.getText().toString();
    String kmFac = etKmFac.getText().toString();
    String remarqueFac = etRemarqueFac.getText().toString();
    float montantFac = Float.parseFloat(etMontantFac.getText().toString());
    String datePaieFac = tvDateAfficheePaiement.getText().toString();

    if(mRowId == null){
        if (cbGarageFac.isChecked()){
            db.insererFacture(itemSpListeVhc, itemSpListeGar, dateFac, libelleFac, remarqueFac, kmFac, montantFac, datePaieFac);
        }
        else{
            db.insererFacture(itemSpListeVhc, -1, dateFac, libelleFac, remarqueFac, kmFac, montantFac, datePaieFac);
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace -1 by a valid foreign key or by itemSpListeGar, it works.

Here is my query :

```
public long insererFacture(long fkVhcFac, long fkGarFac, String dateFac, String libelleFac, String remarqueFac, String kmFac, float montantFac, String datePaieFac){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("fk_vhc_fa", fkVhcFac);
    values.put("fk_gar_fa", fkGarFac);
    values.put("date_fa", dateFac);
    values.put("libelle_fa", libelleFac);
    values.put("remarque_fa", remarqueFac);
    values.put("kilometrage_fa", kmFac);
    values.put("montant_fa", montantFac);
    values.put("date_paie_fa", datePaieFac);
    return db.insert("TB_FACTURE", null, values);   
}
```

Thanks for your help!

PS : I specify that I don't use real FOREIGN KEYS, but the trigger method which is like this :

```
"fk_gar_fa INTEGER CONSTRAINT ct_fk_gar_fa REFERENCES TB_GARAGE(_id),"
```

Comment: Do you allow NULL for the FK column? Try inserting NULL.

Comment: If I replace it by null, that makes a mistake in my code because it needs long type

Comment: Without knowing your exact table structure I can't be sure, but you may have the relationship backwards.  If you *must* have a record in `facture`, but *not* in `garage`, try placing the fk in `garage`, referencing `facture`.  Solves the fk problem, and more accurately models the relationship.

Comment: It could have been but no. A facture concerns 0 or 1 garage, and a garage is concerned by 0 or n factures.
In fact, facture means invoice in English. It's maybe more understandable, knowing this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bypass this, enforcing [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) is at the basis of relational databases!

In your case I'd suggest making a Garage record that says: "no Garage". And use it's primary key as the foreign key when adding a record in the Facture table that does not have an associated Garage.

It's a bit ugly, but either this, or you change your relational database to no longer enforce integrity and you'll open a new can of worms. :)

Comment: I specify that I don't use real foreign keys but the trigger method (I edit my post). So the referential integrity is not applicated, isn't it?

What I don't understand is that I have an example using my method and it works.

Comment: Why is the trigger there if quote:"I must be able to do this because, in my app, it is not an obligation to link a garage to the invoice.". What is the purpose of the trigger then? Why not make a foreign key column that accepts NULL?

Comment: My application needs to be accessible for Android 2.1 Eclair. And the FOREIGN KEYS are not supported on that version (because it contains an old version of SQLIT). That's why I use this method. 

But the principle is the same and fk_gar_fa is supposed to accept NULL, so why doesn't it work? I can't write it in db.insererFacture, it says that it needs long type.

Comment: I finally chose the "ugly method" which consists of create a garage "undefined". It's the simpliest way at the moment and it finally can be helpful for another part of my app.

By the way, thanks for your quick answers :)

Comment: Ah the whole Android 2.1 and older version of SQLlite explains a lot. Indead you then only have the choice of using the "dirty" method with the "undefined garage" or not using any trigger at all and forcing the integrity in your application.